# Need explanation on assembly instructions of K&R fahr-to-cels example

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am stuck learning basics of assembly language with fahrenheit to celsius example from K&R book. Here is C code that I am referring to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int fahr, celsius;
    int lower, upper, step;

    lower = 0;
    upper = 300;
    step = 20;

    fahr = lower;
    while (fahr <= upper) {
        celsius = 5 * (fahr-32) / 9;
        printf("%d\t%d\n", fahr, celsius);
        fahr = fahr + step;
    }
}
```

Along with GCC 4.4.7 (GNU/Linux x86-64) I get following disassembly:

```
$ gcc -O0 -g -ansi -pedantic l1-2a.c
$ gdb -q a.out
(gdb) disas /m main
(gdb) disas /m main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
6   {
   0x00000000004004c4 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x00000000004004c5 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000004004c8 <+4>: sub    $0x20,%rsp

7       int fahr, celsius;
8       int lower, upper, step;
9   
10      lower = 0;
   0x00000000004004cc <+8>: movl   $0x0,-0xc(%rbp)

11      upper = 300;
   0x00000000004004d3 <+15>:    movl   $0x12c,-0x8(%rbp)

12      step = 20;
   0x00000000004004da <+22>:    movl   $0x14,-0x4(%rbp)

13  
14      fahr = lower;
   0x00000000004004e1 <+29>:    mov    -0xc(%rbp),%eax
   0x00000000004004e4 <+32>:    mov    %eax,-0x14(%rbp)

15      while (fahr <= upper) {
   0x00000000004004e7 <+35>:    jmp    0x400532 <main+110>
   0x0000000000400532 <+110>:   mov    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000400535 <+113>:   cmp    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000400538 <+116>:   jle    0x4004e9 <main+37>

16          celsius = 5 * (fahr-32) / 9;
   0x00000000004004e9 <+37>:    mov    -0x14(%rbp),%edx
   0x00000000004004ec <+40>:    mov    %edx,%eax
   0x00000000004004ee <+42>:    shl    $0x2,%eax
   0x00000000004004f1 <+45>:    add    %edx,%eax
   0x00000000004004f3 <+47>:    lea    -0xa0(%rax),%ecx
   0x00000000004004f9 <+53>:    mov    $0x38e38e39,%edx
   0x00000000004004fe <+58>:    mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x0000000000400500 <+60>:    imul   %edx
   0x0000000000400502 <+62>:    sar    %edx
   0x0000000000400504 <+64>:    mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x0000000000400506 <+66>:    sar    $0x1f,%eax
   0x0000000000400509 <+69>:    mov    %edx,%ecx
   0x000000000040050b <+71>:    sub    %eax,%ecx
   0x000000000040050d <+73>:    mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x000000000040050f <+75>:    mov    %eax,-0x10(%rbp)

17          printf("%d\t%d\n", fahr, celsius);
   0x0000000000400512 <+78>:    mov    $0x400638,%eax
   0x0000000000400517 <+83>:    mov    -0x10(%rbp),%edx
   0x000000000040051a <+86>:    mov    -0x14(%rbp),%ecx
   0x000000000040051d <+89>:    mov    %ecx,%esi
   0x000000000040051f <+91>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000400522 <+94>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400527 <+99>:    callq  0x4003b8 <printf@plt>

18          fahr = fahr + step;
   0x000000000040052c <+104>:   mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   0x000000000040052f <+107>:   add    %eax,-0x14(%rbp)

19      }
20  }
   0x000000000040053a <+118>:   leaveq 
   0x000000000040053b <+119>:   retq   

End of assembler dump.
```

What is not clear for me is this fragment:

```
16          celsius = 5 * (fahr-32) / 9;
   0x00000000004004e9 <+37>:    mov    -0x14(%rbp),%edx
   0x00000000004004ec <+40>:    mov    %edx,%eax
   0x00000000004004ee <+42>:    shl    $0x2,%eax
   0x00000000004004f1 <+45>:    add    %edx,%eax
   0x00000000004004f3 <+47>:    lea    -0xa0(%rax),%ecx
   0x00000000004004f9 <+53>:    mov    $0x38e38e39,%edx
   0x00000000004004fe <+58>:    mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x0000000000400500 <+60>:    imul   %edx
   0x0000000000400502 <+62>:    sar    %edx
   0x0000000000400504 <+64>:    mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x0000000000400506 <+66>:    sar    $0x1f,%eax
   0x0000000000400509 <+69>:    mov    %edx,%ecx
   0x000000000040050b <+71>:    sub    %eax,%ecx
   0x000000000040050d <+73>:    mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x000000000040050f <+75>:    mov    %eax,-0x10(%rbp)
```

I mean that I understand everything up to:

```
lea    -0xa0(%rax),%ecx
```

as it is substracting `160` from `%eax` register, that holds `5*fahr`, as:

```
5 * (fahr-32) / 9 <=> (5*fahr - 5*32) / 9 <=> (5*fahr - 160) / 9
```

thus after `%ecx` (as well as complete `%rcx`) stores `5*fahr - 160`. However I don't how it's dividing by 9 then. It seems to be some trickery like "multiply by the inverse" in order to avoid division, but I don't get how it works.

Comment: This is the so-called magic number division. See [here](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/labor-of-division-episode-i.html) for a description.

Comment: `0x38e38e39` = 2^33 / 9.

Comment: Trying to learn assembly by observing compiler generated assembly is probably a bad idea other then to learn that the compiler will probably do it better than you can in all ways accept readability!

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Not exactly as `0x38e38e39` times `9` is `2^33 + 1`. Neverthless I see that point is to multiply by this "magic number", then do (signed) shift to the right, instead of plain division.

Comment: Same [as this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628899/understanding-of-msvs-c-compiler-optimizations/24631005#24631005)

Comment: It's not exactly 2^33 because 2^33 inherently isn't divisible by 9 and you need some rounding and sometimes shift/add to get the correct result like the division. That's why to divide by 10 [MSVC uses the magic number 0x1999999A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558492/divide-by-10-using-bit-shifts) but [ARM GCC uses 0x66666667 and then subtract by `dividend >> 31`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218228/fast-division-on-gcc-arm?lq=1).

Comment: According to [hacker's delight's magic number calculator](http://www.hackersdelight.org/magic.htm) the magic number for signed division is 38E38E39 and shift amount = 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summing up what was said in the comments: `0x38e38e39` is `954437177` in decimal, which is exactly `(2^33 + 1) / 9`. So, the assembly code works this way (I've replaced `(5 * fahr - 160)` with `X` for clarity):

```
mov    $0x38e38e39,%edx /* edx is now 0x38e38e39 == (2^33 + 1) / 9 */
mov    %ecx,%eax        /* eax is now X */
imul   %edx             /* edx:eax is now eax * edx == X * ((2^33 + 1) / 9) */
```

That's where the fun part starts. `edx:eax` stands for the 1-operand `imul` first filling up its operand's (`edx` in this case) 32 bits, and then putting the remaining lower bits into `eax`.

Effectively, we get a 64-bit result across two registers! It looks something like this:

`edx` is the 32 least significant bits of `(X * ((2^33 + 1) / 9)) >> 32`.

`eax` is `(X * ((2^33 + 1) / 9)) % 2^32` (but that's going to be discarded soon)

Then we get this stuff into shape:

```
sar    %edx             /* edx is now edx >> 1 == (X * ((2^33 + 1) / 9)) >> 33 */
mov    %ecx,%eax        /* eax is now X again */
sar    $0x1f,%eax       /* eax is now X >> 0x1f == X >> 31 */
mov    %edx,%ecx        /* ecx is now (X * ((2^33 + 1) / 9)) >> 33 */
```

So now `ecx` is the 32 least significant bits of `(X * ((2^33 + 1) / 9)) >> 33` and `eax` is `X >> 31`, i.e. 32 "sign bit"-s of `X` (which is a signed 32-bit integer), which are equal to `0` if `X` is non-negative and to `-1` if `X` is negative.

**EDIT: detailed elaboration on the special case of negative `X`**

Now a bit about what happens with negative numbers. The important part about `ecx` is that it actually is the 32 most significant bits of `X * ((2^33 + 1) / 9)`.

As I hope you remember, in binary, negating a number means inverting all of its bits and then adding `1` to it. And when we add `1`, we invert the lsb to `1` if it was `0`, otherwise we invert it and all the bits after it 'till we find the first `0` and then invert it too.

So what happens when we try to negate `(X * ((2^33 + 1) / 9))` (or, equivalently, what do we get if we perform calculations with `-X`, considering `X` positive for this example)? Of course, first we invert all of its bits, then we add `1` to it. But for the latter (adding `1` to it) to affect the 32 most siginficant bits of the number, the 32 least significant bits would have to equal `0xFFFFFFFF`. And (trust me on this one) there is no 32-bit integer which, when multiplied by `0x38e38e39`, gives such a result.

So effectively, while `(-X * ((2^33 + 1) / 9)) == -(X * ((2^33 + 1) / 9))`, it's different with the 32 most significant bits: `((-X * ((2^33 + 1) / 9)) >> 33) & 0xFFFFFFFF != -(((X * ((2^33 + 1) / 9)) >> 33) & 0xFFFFFFFF)`.

Instead, the 32 most significant bits of `(-X * ((2^33 + 1) / 9))` equal to the bitwise negation of the 32 most significant bits of `(X * ((2^33 + 1) / 9))`: `((-X * ((2^33 + 1) / 9)) >> 33) & 0xFFFFFFFF != ~(((X * ((2^33 + 1) / 9)) >> 33) & 0xFFFFFFFF)`.

**Tl;dr for negative `X` case:** the value of `ecx` for `-X` will be equal to the bitwise negation of the value of `ecx` for `X`. We don't want that. So to get correct results for negative values of `X`, we'll have to add `1` to `ecx` (or, equivalently, subtract `-1`):

```
sub    %eax,%ecx        /* ecx is now X / 9 */
```

Then comes the last part:

```
mov    %ecx,%eax        /* eax is now X / 9 */
mov    %eax,-0x10(%rbp) /* Aaand mov the result into the variable "cels" */
```

I'm very sorry if I mixed something up, I have trouble keeping my head around asm written in GAS syntax, but I hope you understand the idea.

**Tl;dr:** the trick here is multiplying by the inverse multiplied by a large number, discarding the large number with an arithmetic shift, then rounding the result to zero if it's negative.

**Why all the bother?**

As a result, we stuffed division into 10 cycles (considering `imul` takes only one cycle too). Considering `idiv` can take up to almost twice as much cycles (from 11 to 18 as mentioned by Hans Passant in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628899/understanding-of-msvs-c-compiler-optimizations/24631005#24631005) answer to a similar question), this approach can make a huge performance advantage.